# $X_i \sim N(\mu_i ,1)$ A discussion on unbiased concept

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, inference, unbiased-estimator

I am really confused with following discus.

[image]
 The authors  ask a question and answer it. I have problems to understanding this discussion. For example:
Where come from "upward bias" ? why largest $X_i$ has "upward bias" for its mean? Is this make sense to you?

The discussion about Bayesian approach is not easy to understanding for me? especially 
I do not know what exactly means in this line: "This isn’t obvious, but follows from the fact that any data-based selection process does not affect the likelihood function".

For understanding this discussion , I think a simulation studies works fine. how I can use a simulation studies in R(just needs steps of it and I can do it). thanks.

According what I understand for the patients gen of number $610$  measured
and the mean of it used and it equals $5.29$. so we did not use any order statistics. Am i wrong something? also the plot is the data for all gens not just for gen $610$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
gen number    &  obs_1   &  obs_2  &  \cdots   &  obs_n   &  x_j=mean(x_{ji})=\hat{\mu_j}  \\ \hline   
gen 1    &  x_{11}   &  x_{12}  &  \cdots   &  x_{1n}   &  x_1=mean(x_{1i})=\hat{\mu_1}  \\  \hline
gen 2    &  x_{21}   &  x_{22}  &  \cdots   &  x_{2n}   &  x_2=mean(x_{2i})=\hat{\mu_2}  \\  \hline
.    & .   &  .  & .   &  .   &  .  \\  \hline
gen 610    &  x_{(610)1}   &  x_{(610)2}  &  \cdots   &  x_{(610)n}   &  x_{610}=mean(x_{(610)i})=\hat{\mu_{610}}=5.29  \\  \hline
.    &  .  &  .  & .   & .    & .   \\  \hline
gen N=6033     &  x_{N1}   &  x_{N2}  &  \cdots   &  x_{Nn}   &  x_N=mean(x_{Ni})=\hat{\mu_n}  \\  \hline
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}

[The Source.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf)

Comment: With respect to the question in your next-to-last sentence, yes, you are wrong.  The reason gene 610 was picked for analysis was *because* it had the largest value, i.e., because it was the largest order statistic.   5.29 is therefore the estimate of the largest order statistic, which in this case happened to be for gene 610.

Comment: @ jbowman Tnx for attention.

Comment: @ jbowman. Plz first look at the table at end of question. $x_1 \sim N(\mu_1,1)$, $x_{610}\sim N(\mu_{610} ,1)$. let $x_1<x_{610}$.   I am confused with this:  perhaps in real world $\mu_1 <\mu_{610}$ so x_{610} likely to be greater than  $x_1$. why we should suspect to  $ x_{610}$  upward bias . Perhaps I misunderstood some thing.

Comment: Read my comment again, more carefully.   You are looking at the largest order statistic, which is always biased high relative to the mean, and it just happens to have the label 610.

Answer (score 1):

I will address the upward bias.

The n$^{\text{th}}$ order statistic $X_{(n)}$ (largest value) does not in general have the same distribution as the first order statistic $X_{(1)}$ (smallest value). There is an equation on Wikipedia for calculating the equations for the distributions of order statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics.

From the Wikipedia article:

$$F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = [F_X(x)]^n$$

$$F_{X_{(1)}}(x) = 1-[1-F_X(x)]^n$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$ to get the densities.

For some intuition about why the smallest and largest values should have different distributions, consider $X_1,\dots ,X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$. The expected value of any particular $X_i$ is $0$, yet you would expect the largest $X_i$ to be greater than $0$ and the smallest $X_i$ to be less than zero. With different expected values, the distributions must be different.

Comment: We did not expect $E(X_{610})=0=center \ of \  plot$.

Comment: What did you expect? It sounds like the researchers expected values to be around 0.

Comment: Tnx for attention and your answer. I think the gen 610 calculated for 52 patients $x_{(610,1)},\cdots ,x_{(610,52)}$ and each $X_{(610,i)}\sim N(\mu_610,1)$

Comment: so calculate $x_{610}$ mean of $X_{(610,i)}\sim N(\mu_{610},1)$ I expect $E(X_{610})=\mu_{610}$.The plot is for all gens not just gen 610.

Comment: Not at all clear to me why this answer was downvoted, so I've cancelled that out (+1).